# How does the apparatus is Joule-Thomson Effect work?

Tags: thermodynamics

Can you please explain how the following apparatus works in Joule Thomson Effect works? I searched all over the internet but did not find how the following apparatus works. Please explain.[image: Apparatus]

Comment: The porous plug serves to dissipate the kinetic energy - no average velocity of the gas $\vec{V}$  after the plug exists. It is like a very spoiled Laval nozzle - with a lot of losses due to friction and micro 3D random flows.

Comment: @If there was an average velocity would still the gas heat up (or cooled) but we would need to correct for the average velocity?

Answer (score 0):

In my judgment, the apparatus you have shown is conceptual only, and does not represent any physically realistic system for performing the JT experiment.  I have always envisioned the JT experiment as one being carried out in a continuous flow apparatus, in which the flow system has attained steady state operation.  The upstream pressure and flow rate are established by some sort of centrifugal pump feeding the inlet side of the tube.  The downstream pressure is controlled by some sore of throttling valve substantially downstream of the porous plug.